# what is python runpy module?

Tags: python, runpy

I was wondering the purpose of `runpy` module in Python and how does it help in day to day development of the Python user community?

Can someone please explain the necessity, usage and advantages of `runpy` module in python?

Comment: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/, http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/, https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html Anything *more specific* that isn't clear from those? As it stands your question is rather broad.

Comment: Generally speaking, `runpy` is an implementation detail you don't have to worry about unless you are a Python maintainer or have to debug running a module as a script.

Comment: Even as a module or package developer, all you normally need to know about `runpy` is documented under the [`-m` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs say:

> The runpy module is used to locate and run Python modules without importing them first. Its main use is to implement the -m command line switch that allows scripts to be located using the Python module namespace rather than the filesystem.

You can run a python module like this:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

The `runpy` module enables this functionality. It may not be useful outside of this context.